Is $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac {f(x)} {g(x)} = 0 \implies f \neq \Omega(g)$ true?
I am trying to prove that if for $f: \mathbb{N}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $g:  \mathbb{N}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac {f(x)} {g(x)} = 0 $, then $f \neq \Omega(g)$. My proof is simply that if we assume for contradiction that $ f= \Omega(g) $, then there exists a constant $c$ such that for all sufficiently large $x$, $g(x)\le c \cdot f(x)$, which implies that for some constant $c$, for all sufficiently large $x$, $\frac 1 c\le \frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$; this is a contradiction because $f(x) \over g(x)$ is supposed to be able to be within any real of $0$ for all $x$ after a certain point, if indeed $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac {f(x)} {g(x)} = 0 $.
However, I am unsure of this as my course compiled a lengthy set of statements regarding the asymptotic statements we could conclude of $f$ and $g$ based upon the values of the limit of $f(x) \over g(x)$ at infinity, and this statement was missing. So is this reasoning correct?

So, in the interest of clarity, I'm assuming you're using $\Omega$ as Knuth would use it. I'll assume positive-valued $f,g$ for this discussion; more details can be found on Wikipedia.

Aside: $\Omega$ as used by Knuth, common in complexity theory. $f = \Omega(g)$ essentially is summed up as "there is a scalar multiple of $g$ that, eventually, $f$ outgrows". That is,
$$
\exists M > 0 \text{ such that } \forall x > a \text{ we have } f(x) \ge M g(x)
$$
or
$$\liminf_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} > 0
$$

In that light, I believe your work is fine. However, we can simplify matters greatly, if you have access to the limit-infimum definition.
A known result is that, for sequences $a_n$,
$$
\lim_{n \to n_\ast} a_n = L
\iff
\liminf_{n \to n_\ast} a_n = \limsup_{n \to n_\ast} a_n = L
$$
and in particular,
$$
\liminf_{n \to n_\ast} h(x)
\le \lim_{n \to n_\ast} h(x)
\le \limsup_{n \to n_\ast} h(x)
$$
In that case, the result is immediate as, if $f = \Omega(g)$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$ then
$$
0 < \liminf_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \le \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0
$$
which is nonsensical! (Admittedly, it is largely the same logic you're using, just framed a tad differently.)
